# Unable to see shared workspace in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, cloud, subscription

We are collaborating with multiple people on Azure project. We are sharing one ResourceGroup under MSDN Subscription. I have been assigned the role *Owner* under that subscription. I see all the Azure resources. But when I go to the ML studio workspace, where my role is also *Owner*, which I can see in portal.azure.com, I don't see the workspace in the appropriate Region in the studio.azureml.net. Any suggestions why this might be the case? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

I did a test in my lab and reproduced your issue. Finally I found the cause:

The owner of the workspace didn't invite you as a user or owner of the workspace in Azure machine learning studio.  **Because that the workspace only has one owner at beginning when it was created.** You need to contact the owner who created the workspace to invite you as following steps:

1. Login Azure machine learning studio with owner account.
2. Go to settings> Users > invite more users > input your email address > Click √

[image]

[image]

3. Go to your email and click the link. Then choose the region of the workspace in Machine learning studio, you will see it !

Please let me know if it helps !

Comment: I don't see the `Users` menu in Resource Mangement, I will ask the owner of the ML space. But  I can see `Access control (IAM)` and there I am listed as the owner. I'll let you know when I get  word from my teammate.

Comment: So the `Users` settings are the same as the `IAM` settings and I am listed as the owner there. So as you wrote, I guess I should see it in ML studio, but I don't

Comment: Hi,@JaKu . What's your Studio location?

Comment: Did you try to launch ML studio from portal? Check if  the signed user is as same as the one in portal.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to launch the ML studio from portal (the button highlighted on your first screenshot). I also have the account connected to two usernames and I have tried to login with both of them without any luck.

Comment: Hi,@JaKu, Can you provide screenshots ? It works fine for me, Your issue is a little strange...

Comment: Hi,@JaKu. I have updated my answer, please check it . I found the reason why you cannot see the worksapce.